# Magento 1.9 disable login and registration completely

Tags: magento-1.9, login, registration

I'm looking for way to completely remove customer login and registration, so checkout would be able to do only as guest. I found [this](https://github.com/borasocom-team/Magento-PreventUsersRegistration) extension which disables registration and redirects to login, so my question is will I be able to do something similar to disable login as well, of is there some better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `System -> Configuration -> Advance -> Advance and disbale` the magento customer module output. This will disable the login/ registration and all stuff regarding customer.

Comment: That almost did trick. Looks like there is some 3rd party onepage checkout extension that is requesting fields first name and last name, but they don't exist when checkout as guest is selected. But you answered my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

In my Magento 1.9.2.1 in admin panel:

`System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output -> Mage_Customer -> Disable`

After this click the "Save Config" button.